# How to change language in VSC terminal on macOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find how to change the language in the default VSC terminal to English. The VSC itself has English language but the all info in terminal is presented in the language of my PC. Thanks

Comment: do you use windows? you may be need to change your system to English. Or you should install another shell. MinGW is a choice. it's installed with git for windows

Comment: @JumHorn I use macOS. VSC terminal displays logs in the system language (if the system language is German, then the logs are in German). It started show logs on system language after i downloaded git for mac